# Getting "npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID" on npm packages global install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Whenever I am installing any global package I am getting this error.

> Error:-  on npm packages global install

**For example:-**

```
robins@robins-H61MLV3:~$ sudo npm install -g jshint

/usr/bin/jshint -> /usr/lib/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-25-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "jshint"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.2
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma@0.10.10 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.6.2 wants karma@~0.10.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-mocha@0.1.10 wants karma@>=0.12.8
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.6 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
```

> What I have tried so far

I have tried updating the global karma and its related modules but it didn't worked. I have also tried uninstalling karma modules but the problem persists.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g  karma grunt-karma karma-html2js-preprocessor  karma-mocha karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-script-launcher  karma-jasmine  karma-requirejs karma-coffee-preprocessor
```

Comment: >>npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-mocha@0.1.10 wants karma@>=0.12.8
Is the version of Karma >=0.12.8 in your Package.json ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like karma has some dependencies on other modules that are available (global), but are older.
You'd need to update your global packages using npm update -g

```
npm update -g
```

Basically "npm update -g" just updates all Global packages. "All" because no package name has been provided and "global" because of the "-g" switch.

My suggestion is to first update all of your global packages and then try installing jshint again.

```
sudo npm install -g jshint
```

Comment: tried updating the npm still showing the same error while updating npm too.

Answer (score 10):

update npm by using command

```
npm install npm -g
```

then clean the cache using

```
npm cache clean
```

then install the package as per your requirement.
Hope, this would help all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by just naming my project with a single word instead of a phrase that I had used before.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a fix for NPM, but a workaround in my case (using Ubuntu 16.04) on this issue was to install yarn and run "yarn install" instead of "npm install".