# Ionic invalid package name __ngcc_entry_points__.json

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm almost finished developing my application with ionic and angular.
Unfortunately, I'm totally stuck. I can't build my application (on android) anymore.

Here's the error:

```js
ionic cordova build android
cordova.cmd platform add android --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^8.0.0
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^8.0.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "__ngcc_entry_points__.json": name cannot start with an underscore

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jules\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-09T17_09_27_363Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

This problem had already happened to me on another project. To fix it I just had to search in the file explorer and rename `__ngcc_entry_points__.json` without the underscore of the beginning. Even if some time later it would come back, I just had to rename it to.

Unfortunately, `__ngcc_entry_points__.json` is totally untraceable everywhere in my project. I'm completely blocked.

Comment: May it be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816824/getting-npm-err-code-epeerinvalid-on-npm-packages-global-install

Also you can try to remove node_modules folder and run 'npm install' again

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Solution to this problem is:

```
rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```

Comment: This fixes 99% of problems related with npm.

Comment: Also I needed to delete the `package-lock.json` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63889891/626639

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what the command 'rm -rf node_modules' is actually  telling npm to do.

Comment: @jake rm isn't an npm command, it just deletes the node_modules folder. There's a nice summary of what the flags mean here: https://askubuntu.com/a/670655/938513

Comment: The answer is "Delete node_modules  folder and then run npm install". rm -rf is a command for Linux OS.

Comment: Awful solution. he should just delete __ngcc_entry_points__ entry from package.lock.json

Answer (score 18):

I have often experienced seeing this error message while working on Angular projects. And that prevents adding any dependencies due to the conflicts in the package-lock.json file.
Whereas removing the node modules folder and reinstalling them gets rid of this, it's not always feasible to do that as for bigger projects, it can consume a lot of time.
The solution that works for me is

1. Deleting package-lock.json file
2. Deleting **ngcc_entry_points**.json file from the node_modules folder
3. Running npm install (It just recreates the package-lock.json file)
   And just like that conflicts get resolved! Hope it helps save time for someone.

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem and it was caused due to `__ngcc_entry_points__` element in `package-lock.json` file (can be located in the root directory, next to `package.json`).

Removing the `__ngcc_entry_points__` element from  `package-lock.json`, deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again fixed the problem

Answer (score 8):

For me, the solution was to remove any space from the `"name"` in `package.json`, for example

```
{
  "name": "My App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  ...
```

becomes

```
{
  "name": "My_App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the name of your app in **package.json** is valid.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Answer (score 1):

**Ionic 6+ / Capaciotr 3+**

***Error:***

> Invalid package name "**ngcc_entry_points**.json": name cannot start with an underscore

My issue here was on the `package.json` file:

I have put version like so:  `"version": "1.5.0-build:2",`

But it didn't work. So changed it to:  `"version": "1.5.0",` and no issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I´m new to Angular, and I got this same error when installing OAuth2 complement. It was just the wrong folder (I know, very beginner mistake), if you are trying to run npm command check you are at your common directory.